# Mongoose schema suddenly invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, schema

I'm currently working on a MERN Application. I'm fairly new to backend and database related topics.

I have configured this mongoose model, using the following schema:

`item.model.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const itemSchema = new Schema({
    title: String, // String is shorthand for {type: String}
    author: String,
    body:   String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    meta: {
        reports: {type: Number, default: 0}
    }
});

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);

module.exports = Item;
```

In my `api.js` file, this is how I import the model:

`const Item = require('../models/item.model');`

Now, when starting my server I get following error:

`` TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `String` is not a valid type at path `title` ``

I'm wondering why the type is invalid. I am using the syntax from the mongoose docs.
I did refactor my code and moved my backend folder. I can't imagine that this is related to the error, but since refactoring, this error appeared. I also tried moving the backend folder back where it was but I still get this error.

Comment: Mostly looks like that your define the `String` variable somewhere before this code.

Comment: I actually don't. Is there a way to check this? Can this be related to the refactor? Just for the sake of trying I changed ```String``` to ```Number``` but still gets me the same error.

Comment: I wrote it cause I test your code and it works perfectly for me. You can easely test it to put before `new Schema` `console.log(String)`.

Comment: This frustrates me even more :((. Loging ```String``` returns a function for me, I haven't changed anything or defined any other value for ```String```. Also trying other types as ```Number``` or ```Boolean``` don't work.  
I've tried using mongoose.Schema.Types.String as well, as suggested in your other comment, but that gets me this error: ```TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `title`, got value "undefined"```

Comment: What is your mongoose version?

Comment: `console.log(mongoose.Schema.Types.String) = function SchemaString()`

Comment: I'm using mongoose 5.11.15. Loging mongoose.Schema.Types.String returns undefined for me.

Comment: share github link of your project @R.Fox

Comment: Yep. Github link would be useful. Do you have a mongoose directory in your project?

Comment: This is so strange. I got it to work now. I did set up the entire backend project again and now everything seems to work fine. I'm sure this was related to the refactor. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use another way for type definitions

`title: 'String'`

or

`title: mongoose.Schema.Types.String`